# При использовании метода GET появляется ошибка при не указании переменной

Tags: php, get

> Notice: Undefined index: sub in
>
> /var/www/h31524/data/www/skill.in.ua/s13/includes/new.php on line 49
>
> Notice: Undefined index: sub in
>
> /var/www/h31524/data/www/skill.in.ua/s13/includes/new.php on line 63

---

```
    <?php

    if ( !$n )
    {
        ?>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="title"><?php echo $title[$i]; ?></div>
            <div class="cat"><?php echo $sub[$i] . ',' . $cat[$i]; ?></div>
            <div class="image"><?php echo $image[$i]; ?></div>
            <div class="views"><?php echo $views[$i]; ?></div>
            <div class="description"><?php echo $desc[$i]; ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        if ( $_GET )
        {
            if ( $n !== $cat_num[$i] )
            {
                echo 'В данной категории нет записей';
            }
            else
            {
                if ( $_GET )
                {
                    if ( $_GET['sub'] == $sub[$i] )
                    {
                        ?>

                        <div id="content">
                            <div class="title"><?php echo $title[$n]; ?></div>
                            <div class="cat"><?php echo $sub[$n] . ',' . $cat[$n]; ?></div>
                            <div class="image"><?php echo $image[$n]; ?></div>
                            <div class="views"><?php echo $views[$n]; ?></div>
                            <div class="description"><?php echo $desc[$n]; ?></div>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                    }
                    else if ( $_GET['n'] and !$_GET['sub'] )
                    {
                        ?>

                        <div id="content">
                            <div class="title"><?php echo $title[$n]; ?></div>
                            <div class="cat"><?php echo $sub[$i] . ',' . $cat[$n]; ?></div>
                            <div class="image"><?php echo $image[$n]; ?></div>
                            <div class="views"><?php echo $views[$n]; ?></div>
                            <div class="description"><?php echo $desc[$n]; ?></div>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ?>
                        В данной подкатегории нет записей
                        <?php
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте проверять существования ключа в GET-запросе с помощью функции isset(), и обращайтесь к этому ключу только в том случае если он существует.
И второй вариант - ознакомьтесь с механизмом отображения ошибок http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php, возможно вам подойдёт отключение ошибок уровня "NOTICE".

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное. Через isset все заработало.